# css run keyframes on hover and click

Tags: jquery, css

I've been trying to have this 'button' (actually a 'div') to run through keyframes on hover and 'click'. Currently its working on hover perfectly but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the ripple to work on 'click'/'active' as well as on hover. I've tried a couple of CSS and Jquery fixes to this but nothing I've tried seems to allow the animation the run on both hover and click.

How to get the keyframes to run when the button is clicked?

```js
$('.hvr-ripple-out-good').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fill-good');
});
```

```css
.hvr-ripple-out-good {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:hover {
  color: #39CCCC;
  border-color: #39CCCC;
}


/* Ripple Out */

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:hover:before,
.hvr-ripple-out-good:focus:before,
.hvr-ripple-out-good:active:before {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  border-color: #39CCCC;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:active {
  background-color: #61D6D6;
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
}

.fill-good {
  background-color: #39CCCC; 
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.fill-good:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="hvr-ripple-out-good"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
```

Comment: please state where the code for the animation is.

Comment: Wait, where is the element with the class: .fill-good?

Comment: @RandomChannel, sorry the word animate was misleading, I removed it. the JQ toggles fill-good to add the background colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article:
https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

The ideal way to restart a CSS animation is by cloning and replacing the element. Give it a try with this code:

```
$('.hvr-ripple-out-good').click(function() {
     var el = $(this),  
     newone = el.clone(true);
     el.before(newone);
     el.remove();     
     newone.addClass('fill-good'); //This line is added just for styling
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v0f3dnue/1/

Comment: this almost does the trick but the fill on the background goes when the restart happens.

Comment: You're right considering the context of the answer, that was added because of the OP comment. I'll add a comment in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is how to redo the animation,

```
$('.hvr-ripple-out-good').click(function() {
     var el = $(this),  
     newone = el.clone(true);
     el.before(newone);
     $("." + el.attr("class") + ":last").remove();     
});
```

And add `$(this).toggleClass('fill-good');` to the end of it, so

```
$('.hvr-ripple-out-good').click(function() {
     var el = $(this),  
     newone = el.clone(true);
     el.before(newone);
     $("." + el.attr("class") + ":last").remove(); 
     $(this).toggleClass('fill-good');
});
```

Snippet:

```js
$('.hvr-ripple-out-good').click(function() {
     var el = $(this),  
     newone = el.clone(true);
     el.before(newone);
     $("." + el.attr("class") + ":last").remove(); 
     $(this).toggleClass('fill-good');
});
```

```css
.hvr-ripple-out-good {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:hover {
  color: #39CCCC;
  border-color: #39CCCC;
}


/* Ripple Out */

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:hover:before,
.hvr-ripple-out-good:focus:before,
.hvr-ripple-out-good:active:before {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  border-color: #39CCCC;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:active {
  background-color: #61D6D6;
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
}

.fill-good {
  background-color: #39CCCC; 
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.fill-good:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="hvr-ripple-out-good"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to restart the animation is to use `setTimeout()` as the following.

Note that I separate the animation to a class `.animate`.

```js
$('.hvr-ripple-out-good').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass('fill-good');
  $this.removeClass('animate');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $this.addClass('animate')
  })
});
```

```css
.hvr-ripple-out-good {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:hover {
  color: #39CCCC;
  border-color: #39CCCC;
}


/* Ripple Out */

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.animate:hover:before,
.animate:focus:before,
.animate:active:before {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  border-color: #39CCCC;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.animate:active {
  background-color: #61D6D6;
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
}

.fill-good {
  background-color: #39CCCC; 
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.fill-good:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="hvr-ripple-out-good animate"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
```

Or like **AarónBC.** said, cloning and replacing the original element. I just simplify and correct the method that he provided.

```js
$('.hvr-ripple-out-good').click(function() {
  let $this = $(this)
      $this.toggleClass('fill-good')
      $this.before($this.clone(true)).remove();
});
```

```css
.hvr-ripple-out-good {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:hover {
  color: #39CCCC;
  border-color: #39CCCC;
}


/* Ripple Out */

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:hover:before,
.hvr-ripple-out-good:focus:before,
.hvr-ripple-out-good:active:before {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  border-color: #39CCCC;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:active {
  background-color: #61D6D6;
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
}

.fill-good {
  background-color: #39CCCC; 
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.fill-good:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="hvr-ripple-out-good"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
```